# Question about the conditions for a linear map/transformation

Tags: functions, linear-transformations

I have been taught and always read that there are two conditions required for a map or transformation to be linear is

1. $T(\alpha \textbf{u})=\alpha T(\textbf{u})$
2. $T(\textbf{u}+\textbf{v})=T(\textbf{u})+T(\textbf{v})$

Now my question is, does the second not imply the first? Why are both of these conditions stated? Is there any examples of non-linear mappings in which the second condition is satisfied but the first is not?

Comment: The second only implies the first when $\alpha$ is rational.  See [Cauchy's Functional Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).

Comment: How would the second imply the first exactly? And yes there are examples: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132215/a-real-function-which-is-additive-but-not-homogenous

Comment: @lulu Thank you. I completely ignored the fact that, even in the above, 2 Only deals with integers. The link is very interesting that it extends to all rationals.

Comment: The second condition does not imply the first. Consider $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}$.